# In Express or connect with Node.js, is there a way to call another route internally?

Tags: node.js, routes, express

So, I have the setup like this (in Express):

```
app.get('/mycall1', function(req,res) { res.send('Good'); });
app.get('/mycall2', function(req,res) { res.send('Good2'); });
```

What if I want make an aggregate function to call `/mycall1` and `/mycall2` without rewriting code and reusing code for `/mycall1` and `/mycall2`?

For example:

```
app.get('/myAggregate', function (req, res) {
  // call /mycall1
  // call /mycall2  
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this is not possible without rewriting or refactoring your code. The reason is that [`res.send` actually calls `res.end` after it is done writing](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#res.send%28%29). That ends the response and nothing more can be written.

As you hinted to, you can achieve the desired effect by refactoring the code so that both `/mycall1` and `/mycall2` call separate functions internally, and `/myAggregate` calls both the functions.

In these functions, you would have to use `res.write` to prevent ending the response. The handlers for `/mycall1`, `/mycall2`, and `/myAggregate` would each have to call `res.end` separately to actually end the response.

Answer (score 0):

Like many things in javascript your original goal *can be accomplished* with **sneakiness**. We can overwrite the `res.send` function so that it doesn't call `res.end`; this will allow `res.send` to be called multiple times without issue. Note that this is an ugly, sneaky approach - not recommended, but potentially useful:

```
app.get('myAggregate', (req, res) => {
  // Overwrite `res.send` so it tolerates multiple calls:
  let restoreSend = res.send;
  res.send = () => { /* do nothing */ };

  // Call mycall1
  req.method = 'GET';
  req.url = '/mycall1';
  app.handle(req, res, () => {});

  // Call mycall2
  req.method = 'GET';
  req.url = '/mycall2';
  app.handle(req, res, () => {});

  // Restore `res.send` to its normal functionality
  res.send = restoreSend;

  // Finally, call `res.send` in conclusion of calling both mycall1 and mycall2
  res.send('Good AND Good2!');

});
```