# Request to the an endpoint on the same server in express js

Tags: node.js, express

While handling a request on a express js server, I want to call an endpoint on the same server in order to fill part of the response.  Is there a way I can call an endpoint on the same server?

Something like:

```
app.handle("/abc", {
    headers: {
    },
    params: {
    },
    type: "GET"
}, function (err, resp) {});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Express or connect with Node.js, is there a way to call another route internally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474796/in-express-or-connect-with-node-js-is-there-a-way-to-call-another-route-interna)

Comment: I dont think this is a duplicate.  In that question, the idea is to pass the same req, res object to the new call.  Here, I want to send a new HTTP request to the same server, without actually making a request.get call, but, by using the framework.

Comment: Isn't that the same thing?

Comment: Not sure what `app.handle` is, but using named function and calling it could help here. Concept of middlewares is there for a reason too.

Comment: I can do something like request.get("localhost/abc") for my purpose, but wanted to see if the framework provides any alternative.

Comment: @cpancake, In the other case, the original request and response objects are passed to the new call.  In my case, I want new request object, since the params to the new request would be different from the params of the original request

Comment: Same problem here. It is needed for batch endpoint that allows to execute multiple requests in a single request. I am currently sending actual requests to localhost... But it's difficult to test in this way

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [supertest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest) library (using it in the application, not in the test):

```
var handleRequest = require('supertest');

var request = handleRequest(app)[params.method](params.path)
.set('Accept', 'application/json')
.set(params.headers);

if (body) request.send(params.body);

request.end(function (err, resp) {
  console.log(resp.body);
});
```

where `params` is an object with the parameters of the request you want to process, `params.method` should be lowercase HTTP verb.

Alternatively you can use mocks for request and response objects and call:

```
app.handle(reqMock, resMock, cb)
```