# How to make a GET request on another endpoint in Node?

Tags: node.js, express, https, get

I'd like to set up a Node server where inside one endpoint, a GET request can be made to another endpoint in the same server.

My code for testing this is as follows:

```
const express = require('express');
const app=express();
const https=require("https");

const port=1337;
app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log('live on port '+port);
});



app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.send('Homepage here');
    var url="localhost/test?param=abcde";
    https.get(url,res=>{
      body=JSON.stringify(res);
      console.log(body);
    });
});


app.get('/test',(req,res)=>{
    var response=req.param;
    console.log(response);
    res.send(response);
});
```

When the user goes to the main page, it should send a GET request to `/test` that returns the value specified by `param`.  However, when I open the page, I get this error at the console:

```
Error: Unable to determine the domain name
```

This also happens if I set

```
var url="./test?param=abcde";
```

or

```
var url="/test?param=abcde";
```

What is the correct URL to use for accessing another endpoint in the same `.js` server file?  And is this the correct way to pass a GET parameter into that endpoint and return a result to the calling endpoint?

Note: it is a similar problem to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474796/in-express-or-connect-with-node-js-is-there-a-way-to-call-another-route-interna), but that one doesn't seem to have a workable solution posted, unless there's something useful in [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9479579/619177) that I'm overlooking.

Comment: Why don't you factor out the functionality that's handling the parameter from the request to `/test` and call it directly? So the `/test` function would call `handleParam(req.param)` and the `/` function would call `handleParam('abcde')`, then there's no need for the overhead of another HTTP call.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, This is how I have to set things up, because I'm working with a function that takes a URL as its parameter, and I would like this URL to return some dynamic XML based on a value passed in.  Specifically it's the Twilio function [calls.create()](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/making-calls), where I was thinking about using `url: 'http://myapp.com/voice?param=somevalue'` but I thought it would be good to figure out the basics of how a secondary endpoint processing a GET request would work in Node in general rather than focusing on this narrow use case.

Comment: It's not clear why you think that wouldn't be a general solution. But in any case a quick search identifies multiple existing resources.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Express or connect with Node.js, is there a way to call another route internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474796/in-express-or-connect-with-node-js-is-there-a-way-to-call-another-route-interna)

Comment: See also e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/23987120/3001761, and note that you'd be better looking specifically at Express rather than talking in terms of Node.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the problem seems similar to the [In Express...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474796/in-express-or-connect-with-node-js-is-there-a-way-to-call-another-route-interna) question but I don't see anything there that provides a solution.  I see that the solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23987120/request-to-the-an-endpoint-on-the-same-server-in-express-js) involves a `.end()` call to make the next HTTP request to another endpoint, and that's fine, but I can't figure out how to set up the HTTP request within `end()`.  Sorry if I'm missing the obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have three concerns.

First,
port seems 1337, so shouldn't you request `var url="localhost:1337/test?param=abcde";` instead of `var url="localhost/test?param=abcde";`

Second, do you use `https` or `http`?
If http, use [`http` module](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) instead of `https`.

Third, it's `GET` request and `?param=abcde` is a query parameter, so change to 
`var response=req.query;` instead of `var response=req.param;`
http://expressjs.com/ja/api.html#req.query

I modified the code(in my local environment, this works).
I use `http` module because in my local environment `https` is not supported. But if you use twilio, [you may use `https`](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/http-requests-in-node-js.html)

```
const express = require('express');
const app=express();
const http=require("http");

const port=8080;
app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log('live on port '+port);
});



app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.send('Homepage here');
    var url="http://localhost:8080/test?param=abcde";
    var req = http.request(url,res=>{
      // comment out, because in my environment this causes error
      // body=JSON.stringify(res);
      // console.log(body);
      res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
      });
    });
    req.end();
});


app.get('/test',(req,res)=>{
    console.log('route /test')
    var response=req.query;
    console.log(response);
    res.send(response);
});
```

Output:

```
live on port 8080
route /test
{ param: 'abcde' }
BODY: {"param":"abcde"}
```

Comment: This gave me a `Error: Protocol "localhost:" not supported. Expected "http:"`
When I changed it to `http://localhost:1337/test?param=abcde`, the error did not occur, but neither `console.log(response)` nor `console.log(body)` were called.

Comment: @sigil I added the third point, and modified as you wrote.
But I am not sure this works...

Comment: Tried it with `var response=req.query.param;` and got the same result: no error, no `console.log()` calls.

Comment: Sorry `http` module use was wrong, I modified and test in my local environment.

Answer (score -3):

You should use **http** or **https** in first address

```
var url="http://localhost/test?param=abcde"
// Or
var url="https://localhost/test?param=abcde"
```